# My ASUS U32U with fresh Xubuntu install shows a black screen 50-80% of the startups

Tags: xubuntu, asus

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 with Xubuntu-package on my ASUS U32U notebook (Radeon HD 6320 GPU).

The issue I have is that more often than not, after the GRUB-select screen I get a black screen, and three times total white lines (kind of) flashes very quickly (with maybe 5 seconds between each flash). I'm not even able to get to the login-screen (nor the Xubuntu loading screen).

At first I thought it was simply me having installed something dumb or messed up some settings, but even after reformatting the partition and installing ubuntu again, the problem remains.

Before I formatted it xfce4's window manager wouldn't start either, but it does now (when I am able to see anything).

I can access the virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, but I can't see anything.  I've managed to shutdown the computer by using `sudo shutdown -h now`

Answer (score 1):

Got exactly the same problem installing Ubuntu 12.10 on an Asus X32U.

The "release notes" suggest that you need to "nomodeset" in the kernel boot options.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/725580

This was pretty meaningless to me a few days ago but this brilliant post should help you.... http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: Huh, now the xubuntu loading screen actually shows up (where before there were just a flash of lines), and if I erase the "splash" option in boot I'll instead see a bunch of text rows. The issue remains though, since after that the screen turns black again, now without any flashes (so just a single flash, but where I actually see xubuntu loading).